# Error with SQL stored procedure output type

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table 2 tables, namely DAH_Errors and Intraday_Errors, and I want to calculate some statistical performance indicators, fore example the NMAE over a specified range of rows. The range is specified by 2 variables @fromdate and @todate, as shown below:

```
DECLARE @fromdates VARCHAR(20)='2017-12-11 00:15:00'
DECLARE @todates VARCHAR(20)='2017-12-12 00:00:00'
DECLARE @fromdate SMALLDATETIME=CAST(@fromdates AS SMALLDATETIME)
DECLARE @todate SMALLDATETIME=CAST(@todates AS SMALLDATETIME)

DECLARE @nmae1 DECIMAL(20,5)
DECLARE @nmae DECIMAL(20,5)
DECLARE @nrmse1 DECIMAL(20,5)
DECLARE @nrmse DECIMAL(20,5)
```

In order to calculate the NMAE, I have created a the procedure get_nmaev2, which is the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_NMAEv2]
        @forecasttype VARCHAR(MAX),
        @fromdate2 SMALLDATETIME,
        @todate2 SMALLDATETIME,
        @nmae DECIMAL(20,5) OUTPUT
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @aux VARCHAR(MAX)='Hello'
IF @forecasttype='DAH'
    SET @aux='SELECT '+@nmae+'=AVG(ABS(['+@forecasttype+'_Errors].[Forecast]-['+@forecasttype+'_Errors].[Metering])/CAST(['+@forecasttype+'_Errors].[Capacity] AS DECIMAL(20,5)))
    FROM dbo.'+@forecasttype+'_Errors
    WHERE ['+@forecasttype+'_Errors].[DateTime(UTC)]>='+@fromdate2+' AND ['+@forecasttype+'_Errors].[DateTime(UTC)]<='+@todate2+' AND ['+@forecasttype+'_Errors].[NAE] IS NOT NULL;'
    EXEC(@aux)

IF @forecasttype='Intraday'
    SET @aux='SELECT '+@nmae+'=AVG(ABS(['+ @forecasttype+'_Errors].[Forecast]-['+@forecasttype+'_Errors].[Onlline])/CAST(['+@forecasttype+'_Errors].[Capacity] AS DECIMAL(20,5)))
    FROM dbo.'+@forecasttype+'_Errors
    WHERE ['+@forecasttype+'_Errors].[DateTimeUTC]>='+@fromdate2+' AND ['+@forecasttype+'_Errors].[DateTimeUTC]<='+@todate2+' AND ['+@forecasttype+'_Errors].[NAE] IS NOT NULL;'
    EXEC(@aux)
```

The variables @fromdate2,@todate2 are used in the WHERE statement in order to specify the range over which I will calculate the NMAE.

I then execute the following, in order to get my result:

```
EXEC dbo.get_nmaev2
     @forecasttype='DAH',  
     @fromdate2 =  @fromdate,
     @todate2 = @todate,
     @nmae=@nmae1 OUTPUT
```

What I want to do, is to store value of the select statement in the variable @nmae, and output that to the variable @nmae1, shown in the first script where I call execute the procedure. However, I get the following error message:

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure get_NMAEv2, Line 16
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
```

I can not find what causes the error, so I would really appreciate some help here. Does this happen because I am trying to include the variable @nmae in the dynamic SQL statement;

I know what the error itself actually means, but I simply cant find what causes it :)

Comment: Cloud you please add the value of @aux variable before execute it?

Comment: Also add the table definitions for Intraday__Errors and DAH_Errors. The problem could be in your calculations too.

Comment: Just did it. Added the value 'HELLO' by doing this: DECLARE @aux VARCHAR(MAX)='HELLO' . Still the same error though :)

Comment: My calculations are fine, because I have made a hardcoded version of this, where I do not use the variable @forecasttype to specify the name of the tables within the SELECT statement, and that actually works as it should.

Comment: I mean the value of the @aux dynamic statement before to call exec(@aux). Add it to the question please

Comment: Use `print @aux` or `select @aux` to get it value before to call `exec (@aux)`

Comment: I added a random value to aux prior to execution. When I try to print aux, it just prints the value HELLO as it should

Answer (score 1):

This row causes your error:

> ```
> SET @aux='SELECT '+@nmae
> ```

Since `@nmae` is `DECIMAL(20,5)` there is no way to make a sum without converting, and thanks to type precedence, it's string `SELECT` that should be converted to numeric, and this is impossible.

Here is quick repro:

```
declare @nmae DECIMAL(20,5); 

DECLARE @aux VARCHAR(MAX)='Hello'

SET @aux='SELECT '+@nmae;

exec(@aux);
```

To see what is converted to what you can use this query:

```
select '2' + 2
```

this will not produce '22', but 4, as it's tring '2' to be converted to numeric, not viceversa.

**UPDATE**

You can use `synonym` to get rid of all your dynamic code like this:

```
declare @forecasttype VARCHAR(MAX) = 'DAH'
declare @sql varchar(8000) = 'create synonym dbo.MySyn for ['+@forecasttype+'_Errors]';
exec(@sql); -- this will create MySyn that points to your table
```

Now you can use the created synonym instead of your table:

```
SELECT @nmae=AVG(ABS([MySyn].[Forecast]-[MySyn].[Metering‌​])/CAST([MySyn]‌​.[Capacity] AS DECIMAL(20,5))) from dbo.[MySyn]
```

And it's even better create an `alias` to not rewrite table name every time in the `select`:

```
SELECT @nmae=AVG(ABS(s.[Forecast]-s.[Metering‌​])/CAST(s.[Capacity] AS DECIMAL(20,5))) from [MySyn] s
```

At the end of sp just drop the `synonym`.

You should be sure that this sp is not executed at the same time by more than 1 user, if it's so you need other solution

Comment: I just realized that everything enclosed within quotes should actually be of VARCHAR type. But in this case, how can I get the value of nmae that I want and output it to the script that executes the procedure?

Comment: You can use sp_executesql to get your output as a variable. But your query should be rewritten to use only parameters, it should not have dynamic table names like this:  ['+@forecasttype+'_Errors].[DateTime(UTC)]

Comment: Can you please provide me the most minimal example you can think of? it would be a great help as I am new to SQL and I have never used sp_executesql

Comment: If you have a table name that can be different at every execution you can use synonym. I mean, at the beginning of your sp, create a sysnonym with fixed name that you'll be use in your query, this way your query need not to by dynamic. At the end of procedure, drop your synonym

Comment: So in the SELECT statement: `SELECT @nmae=AVG(ABS([DAH_Errors].[Forecast]-[DAH_Errors].[Metering])/CAST([DAH_Errors].[Capacity] AS DECIMAL(20,5)))` , how can I replace the `DAH` part of the table name with a variable, so that it can actually be kind of dynamic? should that be a string or..?

Comment: Perfect. This actually helped me a lot to understand your moethodology. The only thing I am still trying to figure out is, how do you actually execute using the sp_executesql?

Comment: When I answered about sp_executesql I did not look with attention at your code, I thought there were many parameters that you passed in, in this case sp_executesql could help. Then I saw that the output parameter was the only parameter there, and you used dynamic code not to concatenate parameters but tu pass table name, so I opted for synonym